# Toggle Password Visibility for multiple password inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So if I'm using on input I can toggle password visibility.
I'm having trouble with it only toggling one input at a time.
D

Currently my code looks like this..

```
  const [isPasswordShown, setPasswordShown] = useState(false);

  const togglePassword = () => {
    setPasswordShown(isPasswordShown ? false : true);
  };

  const renderTogglePasswordIcon = () => {
    return (
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        onClick={togglePassword}
        icon={isPasswordShown ? faEye : faEyeSlash}
      />
    );
  };



              <Input
                variant={InputVariants.text}
                type={isPasswordShown ? "text" : "password"}
                name="password"
                label="Password"
                error={errors.password?.message}
                onChange={(e) => handlePasswordInput(e)}
                ref={register}
              />
              <i>{renderTogglePasswordIcon()}</i>
              <Input
                variant={InputVariants.text}
                type={isPasswordShown ? "text" : "password"}
                name="passwordConfirmation"
                label="Confirm Password"
                error={errors.passwordConfirmation?.message}
                ref={register}
                onChange={(e) => confirmPassword(e)}
              />
              <i>{renderTogglePasswordIcon()}</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to toggle the inputs separately or only one of the inputs?

I would only use the toggle function for one input element. So you can set the html type to password hardcoded in the second element:

```
  <Input
            variant={InputVariants.text}
            type={isPasswordShown ? "text" : "password"}
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            error={errors.password?.message}
            onChange={(e) => handlePasswordInput(e)}
            ref={register}
          />
          <i>{renderTogglePasswordIcon()}</i>
          <Input
            variant={InputVariants.text}
            type="password"
            name="passwordConfirmation"
            label="Confirm Password"
            error={errors.passwordConfirmation?.message}
            ref={register}
            onChange={(e) => confirmPassword(e)}
          />
          <i>{renderTogglePasswordIcon()}</i>
```

Otherwise you can use a second parameter

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to toggle them separately.